# Software update hinders rebooting OSX

Tags: macos, software-update, reboot

I'm trying to reboot Mountain Lion but it will not allow me. It just keeps saying Waiting... without anything happening. What can I do?

See this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press command + shift + escape and Force Quit the App Store. You can try updating again after App Store is quit.

If this is a recurring issue, try to install small updates first, one by one.

Comment: I was able to force quit but now whenever I try to run the App Store it's just the spinning beachball and nothing happens. Can I "reset" some App Store preference or something?

Comment: Not all problems are solved by resetting preferences. In fact, I don’t think App Store even has a worthy preference file. Did you try to restart your Mac? Are you on 10.8.0 or 10.8.1?

Comment: I restart brought App Store back to normal. I try to avoid the restart as much as possible :-)

Comment: Restarts usually solve stuff :)